# How to add the input username in fosCommentBundle without fosUser?

Tags: php, symfony4, foscommentbundle

I want to add the Username field (input) in bundle FOSCommentBundle without using FOSUserBundlde.

the user must enter his username and comment.
The basic model does not offer the pseudo field because it relies on the connected user or "anonymous" if no connected user.

Can you tell me how to do this?

Symfony 4.4

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in the bundle is just an entity decalred in the configuration. I suppose you did that ?

### Create your own comment entity

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2a-mapping_orm.md

So I think you just have to add new property `$userName` to your comment entity. I found this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/issues/334

### Overriding bundle parts

I never used that bundle but what is answered in the issue comment is pure symfony behavior. You have to override Bundle's Form and template.

That Form : 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Form/CommentType.php

And that template :
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Thread/comment_new_content.html.twig

To override the FormType from any bundle

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/create_form_type_extension.html

and to override templates

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates